# Question - Load data paged from Database and still use Pagination from Angular Material

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a table with more than 1000 entries which I want to display in a `<mat-table></mat-table>`.

Since I do not want to load over thousand entries at once I want to load them paged (20 entries at once).

In the Documentation of "Paginator" , it states, that the "Paginator" needs all entries when loaded.

> Each paginator instance requires:
> The number of items per page (default set to 50) &
> The total number of items being paged

https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/overview

Is there a way to still be able to use the Angular Material Paginator without providing all entries at once?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api

Going through the above documentation, we know that it emits an event page whenever the page is changed.

Initially, when the data is loaded we have only first page rows that we got from server, so the next page is blocked. So, from the backend, along with current set of rows, also populate the total number of rows available and set it to the length before assigning the data to datasource, in this way the mat paginator behaves like it has all the data.

In simple word obj.length = response.total This will add a null value for every data that is not available.

In every page event, we make another API call and add the data in the required index. The event provides all the necessary data index, size, and previous index.

Example Reference Code:

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatPaginator, PageEvent } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  users: any[];
  loading: boolean = true;
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>();

  title = 'pagination';

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData('0', '5');
  }

  getData(offset, limit){
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.set('offset', offset);
    params = params.set('limit', limit);

    this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/users?' + params.toString())
    .subscribe((response: any) =>{

      this.loading = false;
      this.users = response.users;
      this.users.length = response.total;

      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.users);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

    })
  }

  getNextData(currentSize, offset, limit){
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.set('offset', offset);
    params = params.set('limit', limit);

    this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/users?' + params.toString())
    .subscribe((response: any) =>{

      this.loading = false;

      this.users.length = currentSize;
      this.users.push(...response.users);

      this.users.length = response.total;

      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.users);
      this.dataSource._updateChangeSubscription();

      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  
    })
  }

  pageChanged(event){
    this.loading = true;

    let pageIndex = event.pageIndex;
    let pageSize = event.pageSize;

    let previousIndex = event.previousPageIndex;

    let previousSize = pageSize * pageIndex;

    this.getNextData(previousSize, (pageIndex).toString(), pageSize.toString());
  }
}
```

getNextData(currentSize, offset, limit) is the methods you are interested in. As we had already set the length to total, pushing additional data will add it after the index (living those null value in the middle) so we should set back the size to currentSize and push data and set its size to the total.

Reference: https://www.bloggernepal.com/2020/04/angular-material-data-table-paginator-with-server-side-pagination.html

Github Repo Link: https://github.com/InfoDevkota/Server-Side-Pagination-Mat-Paginator

Comment: Thank you! This is a very good answer and it worked!